# Can symlink or bootloaders be used to gain space/boot off a microSD?

Tags: windows, laptop, symbolic-link, bootloader, micro-sd-card

I have a basic notebook that came with Windows 10 but only has 32 gigs HD space. After updates windows literally could not install all of it because of the size. It does have a microSD slot and I have a 128 gig microSD on it, but I don't think it can boot off it. There are a a lot options in the BIOS but nothing that seemed like it could boot oft he microSD slot. It was possible using a USB though (but that for me isn't a great option.) So I'm looking for any ideas.

I was wondering about symbolic links on windows and was wondering if some of the windows folder could be moved off that way. AKA making a folder not he 128 gig with some folders that could be moved. Question is if this is even possible. symbolic links I am guessing wouldn't work while it's in BIOS, but maybe I'm wrong.

Another question I had is if there is some sort of boot loaders that activate/make the SDcard work, and then boot into windows that way. I'm not sure what exactly I could be looking for here or if it's even possible.

If anyone has any other ideas too, I'm open for suggestions. Thanks!